# Ajax Call not hitting servlet in tomcat 8

Tags: ajax, servlets

I have a servlet with following code

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/attachmentUpload.do")
@MultipartConfig
public class AttachmentUploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

if (operationName != null && operationName.equalsIgnoreCase("attachToSNOW")) {
                JSONArray runbookRows = new JSONArray(request.getParameter("runbook"));
                LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "runbook rows:{0}", runbookRows.toString());
}
}
}
```

and ajax call from jsp like this

```
 $.ajax({
                    url: "attachmentUpload.do",
                    method: "post",
                    data: {"operationName": "attachToSNOW",
                        "runbook": JSON.stringify(rowArray)

                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log("ajax called");
                    },
                    error: function (msg) {
                        console.log("Couldn't attach file");
                    }
                });
```

The ajax call just doesn't seem to hit the servlet where my application is deployed(tomcat 8) whereas the same works in a local tomcat attached to Netbeans.

Am totally clueless as to what is the issue.

Stuck on this for couple of weeks now

EDIT
The real issue was, when I was opening a child jsp from parent jsp. In child JSP I was dumping some data into a temp file that would later on be pushed to a web service, the ajax call mentioned was in child jsp. and I was getting no logs in tomcat stdout(also so temp file creation) , hence I understood that part of the code wasn't being reached.

as soon as I changed the ajax call to below, things started working :)

```
 $.ajax({
                    url: "attachmentUpload.do",
                    method: "post",
                     **async: false,
                    cache: false,**
                    data: {"operationName": "attachToSNOW",
                        "runbook": JSON.stringify(rowArray)
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        window.opener.log("ajax called");
                    },
                    error: function (msg) {
                        console.log("Couldn't attach file");
                    }
                });
```

async and cache seem to have done the magic

Comment: did you try with `absolute path`  of your website ?

Comment: Absolute path as in????I tried it by deploying on local tomcat..works perfectly..teh problem is on the server where app is deployed

Comment: What do the browser developer tools tell you?

Comment: EDIT added, browser developer tools helped to debug, I saw the log in parent jsp that I pumped from the child jsp after the ajax was done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding async and cache solved my problem

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "attachmentUpload.do",
                    method: "post",
                     async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    data: {"operationName": "attachToSNOW",
                        "runbook": JSON.stringify(rowArray)
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        window.opener.log("ajax called");
                    },
                    error: function (msg) {
                        console.log("Couldn't attach file");
                    }
                });
```